# Generating a random UUID in C

Tags: c, uuid

How would I go about generating an entropy-based UUID in C and storing it as a string (char pointer)?

I'm hoping that there is an easy way to do this internally, but `system("uuidgen -r")` will work if not.

Comment: Your OS might have libuuid available.  On mine `man 3 uuid` tells me about it.  `man -k uuid` might show you other options.

Comment: You need to link your program with libuuid, of course.

Comment: Look at the other `uuid_*` man pages.  My guess is that you have a uuid but that it is in binary format.  You prolly need to convert it to text in some way.  On my machine there is a library function `uuid_unparse()` and others. EDITED.

Comment: Use, `getrandom` from `<sys/random.h>` for an entropy based 16-byte value. Then simply use `sprintf` (with `%02x`) in a loop to fill your `uuid` buf inserting a `'-'` after the 8th, 13th, 18th and 23rd characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm going to play around with `uuid_generate` a little more, but I'll do that if I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Billy - drop a comment if you can't get your solution working. Getting a completely portable solution can be tricky as different compilers support various entropy based random byte generation. `getrandom` has been present for Linux since the 3.17 kernel, but some Linux distributions incorrectly package header files necessary for its use in userspace. A direct syscall can be used in its absence. If you are on windoze, then you will have to find whatever it uses for random bytes.

Comment: But `libuuid` is nice too, you can do the same thing (portably) with 4-lines of code, two of which are `uuid_generate_random (uuid);`, and `uuid_unparse (uuid, buf);` (the other two lines declare `uuid` and `buf`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, I feel like I might as well use specialized functions for stuff like that if I have them available, instead of doing it manually.

Comment: That is usually good policy. Widely used libraries are generally much more well tested than anything you could come up with on the fly (and better optimized). However, in this case, they basically do the same thing (just with a lot more checks for system portability than would be included in a raw example. `:)`

Comment: @DavidC: that does not guarantee a valid UUID, and even if valid, it may collide with a non-random UUID that was supposed to be non-collideable. There is a reason for libraries.

Comment: @StephenSprunk I thought that was clear from the *"Widely used libraries are generally much more well tested than anything you could come up with on the fly (and better optimized).*" comment above. That's why a well tested library is always a first choice.

Comment: UUIDs are not just random digits. Some of the digits include version and variant information. See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This functionality is provided by `libuuid`. (Packages `libuuid1` and `uuid-dev` on Debian.)

This is a simple program that generates an entropy-based (random) UUID and writes it to `stdout`, then exits with status `0`.

```
/* For malloc() */
#include <stdlib.h>
/* For puts()/printf() */
#include <stdio.h>
/* For uuid_generate() and uuid_unparse() */
#include <uuid/uuid.h>


/* Uncomment to always generate capital UUIDs. */
//#define capitaluuid true

/* Uncomment to always generate lower-case UUIDs. */
//#define lowercaseuuid true

/*
 * Don't uncomment either if you don't care (the case of the letters
 * in the 'unparsed' UUID will depend on your system's locale).
 */


int main(void) {
    uuid_t binuuid;
    /*
     * Generate a UUID. We're not done yet, though,
     * for the UUID generated is in binary format 
     * (hence the variable name). We must 'unparse' 
     * binuuid to get a usable 36-character string.
     */
    uuid_generate_random(binuuid);

    /*
     * uuid_unparse() doesn't allocate memory for itself, so do that with
     * malloc(). 37 is the length of a UUID (36 characters), plus '\0'.
     */
    char *uuid = malloc(37);

#ifdef capitaluuid
    /* Produces a UUID string at uuid consisting of capital letters. */
    uuid_unparse_upper(binuuid, uuid);
#elif lowercaseuuid
    /* Produces a UUID string at uuid consisting of lower-case letters. */
    uuid_unparse_lower(binuuid, uuid);
#else
    /*
     * Produces a UUID string at uuid consisting of letters
     * whose case depends on the system's locale.
     */
    uuid_unparse(binuuid, uuid);
#endif

    // Equivalent of printf("%s\n", uuid); - just my personal preference
    puts(uuid);

    return 0;
}
```

`uuid_unparse()` doesn't allocate it's own memory; to avoid a segmentation fault upon execution you must do that with manually with `uuid = malloc(37);` (you can also store the UUID in a char array of that length: `char uuid[37];`). Make sure to compile with `-luuid` so that the linker knows that `uuid_generate_random()` and `uuid_unparse()` are defined in `libuuid`.

Comment: You can use `UUID_STR_LEN` from the same uuid library instead of hardcoding `37`.

Comment: Please add a `free` to the `malloc`. Such a memory leak should not be multiplied by copy&paste of people finding this answer useful.

Answer (score 5):

Since everyone is saying to use a library, I figured I'd write a fast-and-dirty-C-only version using C's `rand()`. Make sure to call `srand` somewhere so the random UUIDs are actually somewhat random.

There's no guarantees that it won't generate two identical UUIDs, and there's no guarantee this meets whatever standard UUIDs have. As far as I know, they're just random hexadecimal strings with dashes between blocks. Also, this isn't multithreading safe.

```
char* gen_uuid() {
    char v[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    //3fb17ebc-bc38-4939-bc8b-74f2443281d4
    //8 dash 4 dash 4 dash 4 dash 12
    static char buf[37] = {0};

    //gen random for all spaces because lazy
    for(int i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
        buf[i] = v[rand()%16];
    }

    //put dashes in place
    buf[8] = '-';
    buf[13] = '-';
    buf[18] = '-';
    buf[23] = '-';

    //needs end byte
    buf[36] = '\0';

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not contain the memory leak of the previous answer. So I would consider it the more valid one despite the votes.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use <uuid/uuid.h>, which for me on Ubuntu 20.x is located in /usr/include/uuid/.

```
/* uuid.c
 * 
 * Defines function uuid
 *
 * Print a universally unique identifer, created using Linux uuid_generate.
 *
 * 
 * Compile
 *
 * gcc uuid.c -o uuid -luuid -Wall -g
 *
 *
 * Run
 * 
 * ./uuid
 * 
 *
 * Debug
 *
 * gdb uuid
 * b main
 * r
 *
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

char* uuid(char out[UUID_STR_LEN]){
  uuid_t b;
  uuid_generate(b);
  uuid_unparse_lower(b, out);
  return out;
}

int main(){
  char out[UUID_STR_LEN]={0};
  puts(uuid(out));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: compilation errors in code

Comment: Hmm, this still compiles and runs for me just fine using the provided instructions. My gcc version is 11.3.0. Did you name the file you copied the code into "uuid.c" like the compilation instructions expect? If not, what platform and compiler version you using?

Comment: Thank you for refraining the usage of  hard coded values like the `37` in the code of the other two answers.

Comment: Worked out of the box on my system.